# Android: Saving constucted image on screen

Tags: android, image, opengl-es

My users are going to construct and image out of other images in the game, what I then need to take is capture the image they have created and save it.

Im really not sure how to capture the final image, I am using OpenGL ES so the Canvas option is viable

Thanks

Comment: Haven't done a lot with GL, but can you render to a texture and create a bitmap from that?

Comment: I can draw several different bitmaps to the screen but I dont know how to take all of the chosen pictures, combine them and then save that image

Comment: Look at `View.getDrawingCache()`, see here: http://tinyurl.com/3mdoudm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [glReadPixels](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html#glReadPixels%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.nio.Buffer%29) is probably what you're looking for. [Khronos](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/) has better documentation of this function.